# Get controls that implement an interface using Linq?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a number of controls that inherit from a generic base class and this class implements an interface `IMyInterface`.

So far I tried:

```
var results = from c in this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
              where c.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyInterface))
              select c as IMyInterface;
```

However, the above doesn't return any results even though it should.

How can I use Linq to get a list of controls on a form that implement this interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following extension method:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

You want something like:

```
        var result = from c in this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                     where c.GetType().BaseTypesAndSelf().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseGeneric<>))
                     select c;
```

You might want to have your `BaseGeneric<T>` inherit from some even more abstract `BaseGenericBase`, or implement some non-generic `IBaseGeneric` interface, to make this sort of thing simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you could basically use:

`var results = this.Controls.OfType<BaseGeneric>().ToList();`

Comment: `OfType<IMyInterface>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        A test1 = new A();
        B test2 = new B();
        C test3 = new C();

        List<object> test4 = new List<object>() { test1, test2, test3 };
        List<object> test5 = test4.FindAll(x => x is A).ToList();

    }
}

public class A
{

    public A() { }

}

public class B
{

    public B() {}


}

public class C : A
{

    public C()
        :base()
    {

    }

}
```